# cascade persist option doesnt work on ajax submit(api)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, symfony-forms, cascade

I'm working with symfony 3.4.6 and fosrestbundle. I have three entities related as follow:

> Embarque class

```
class Embarque{
//...

/**
     * @var EmbarqueContenedor[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("contenedores")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EmbarqueContenedor",mappedBy="embarque",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $contenedores;

public function addEmbarqueContenedor($embarqueContenedor)
    {
        if (!$this->contenedores->contains($embarqueContenedor)) {
            $this->contenedores->add($embarqueContenedor);
            //$embarqueContenedor->setEmbarque($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeEmbarqueContenedor($embarqueContenedor)
    {
        if ($this->contenedores->contains($embarqueContenedor)) {
            $this->contenedores->removeElement($embarqueContenedor);
        }
    }

}
```

> EmbarqueContenedor class

```
class EmbarqueContenedor{
/**
     * @var Embarque
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Embarque",inversedBy="contenedores",)
     */
    private $embarque;

    /**
     * @var Contenedor
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Contenedor",inversedBy="embarques")
     */
    private $contenedor;
}
```

> Contenedor class

```
class Contenedor{
/**
     * @var EmbarqueContenedor[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("contenedorEmbarques")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EmbarqueContenedor",mappedBy="contenedor")
     */
    private $embarques;

public function addEmbarqueContenedor($embarqueContenedor)
    {
        if (!$this->embarques->contains($embarqueContenedor)) {
            $this->embarques->add($embarqueContenedor);
            $embarqueContenedor->setContenedor($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeEmbarqueContenedor($embarqueContenedor)
    {
        if ($this->embarques->contains($embarqueContenedor)) {
            $this->embarques->removeElement($embarqueContenedor);
        }
    }
}
```

in forms is as follow

```
class EmbarqueType{
$builder->add('contenedores', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => EmbarqueContenedorType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
            ]);
}

class EmbarqueContenedorType{
$builder->add('contenedor', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Contenedor::class,
            ])
}
```

The entity contenedor is create apart and selected in EmbarqueContenedorType when adding or editing, the EmbarqueContenedorEntity is created from EmbarqueType.

The problem is that the records are persisted in the database but with out any reference. The EmbarqueContenedor table has no reference for the Embarque or Contenedor tables.

There is no error because the data is persisted but not referenced. How could this be??

Thanks in advance!

> Edit

I noticed that I was not serializing the Id property of Contenedor Entity so is imposible to make the reference, now is fixed but the Embarque entity still not being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the design of the tables relationships. The table/entity `EmbarqueContenedor` is unnecessary. When you have a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relation just say that to the Doctrine and the Doctrine takes care of the rest (Doctrine will create all necessary tables).

So the solution should be to define your relations with [ManyToMany](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) annotation.

Comment: I can't do that because my bussiness logic leads me to add some custom fields in the many to many relationship, so the EmbarqueContenedor entity is necessary. Thanks any way